# No injectable members on android.app.Application. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by provideOkHttpClient

Tags: android, dagger

I am trying to merge [U2020](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020) and Dagger's example `android-activity-graphs` in the following [repo](https://github.com/kamoljan/Nefete).

However, I am getting compile time error:

```
Error:(32, 8) error: No injectable members on android.app.Application. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by provideOkHttpClient(android.app.Application) for org.kamol.nefete.ActivityModule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't bound `Application`, you have only bound `Context`, but somewhere else in your graph, you have some type that depends on `Application`.  Downstream dependencies which need `Application` will attempt to implicitly bind it because Dagger cannot know that an object which requires `Application` can be satisfied by `@ForApplication Context`.  Since `Application` does not have an @Inject constructor nor @Inject fields, Dagger will fail.

You can fix your example by simply adding

```
@Provides @Singleton Application provideApplicationContext() {
  return application;
}
```

in `org.kamol.nefete.AndroidModule`

As an aside, I recommend against binding `Context` as it is too abstract a supertype and too easy to confuse with `Activity` `Context`s, even if you are binding with a `@Qualifier` annotation, such as `@ForApplication Context`.  I would recommend instead binding `Application` and having things depend on the more concrete type.